# AWS clone instance to many regions and set GeoDNS (Route 53)

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I have an AWS instance working, and I need to clone it to other regions of the world.

I have a single domain name registered via Route 53.  My problem is the domain, despite attempts to configure properly, only direct the request locally to my bastion instance serving from `us-east-2` in Ohio .

I have another (testing) instance in France which I can't seem to get the GeoDNS on Route 53 to direct to these regions when testing via a France VPN.

I wish to have more regions covered by cloning the (US bastion) instance to other regions, along with the attached disk volume.

Few questions arise during my quest:

Is there a way to have the disk volume centralized to each of these instances to simplify any changes to the mongo database running inside the instance volume?

What do I need to look out for in the Route 53 DNS setup?

Comment: What do you mean by "centralized to each of these instances"?

Comment: 1 storage container... accessible by many instances.

Answer (score 0):

Storage can be accessed from other instances in a variety of ways, including glusterfs, sshfs, DRBD, samba/CIFS and NFS.  These have varying pros and cons, including various levels of security for data transiting the public internet.  It is alternatively possible to synchronize using `rsync` or using application layer (e.g. DB) replication.

As ServerFault is not the place to write a comparative review or give product recommendations, these options should be researched and then if necessary ask specific questions.

Importantly, note that having centralized storage may diminish the benefit of distributing nodes geographically, since data could end up having to be fetched from one central location anyway.  In fact, raw storage mounted remotely may be even slower because all the data needed to perform a calculation is transferred from the central point rather than just the results.  However, this may or may not be true for you - it very much depends on the architecture of your application.

Regarding Route53, it is a matter of following the documentation.  If there are particular issues then you should include in the question what you have done so far and the test results - what "to look out for" is too general of a question.